# Why does insert-mode map "<F4>" unpredictably inserts itself or executes intended key strokes?

Tags: vim, xterm, cygwin, key-mapping, vimrc

In Vim 7.3.1-762, mintty 1.1.2 (xterm), cygwin, Windows XP, the insert-mode map `<F4>` executes the intended key strokes at one time but inserts itself at another time. This undeterministic behavior especially occurs if I hold the `<F4>` key depressed.

How do I make the behavior predictable accross multiple Vim-, terminal- and operating system versions?

This is the code I defined in my `~/.vimrc` file, that seems relevant to me:

```
set compatible
set timeout
set ttimeout
set timeoutlen=1000
set ttimeoutlen=100
imap <F4> <C-\><C-O>:set relativenumber! relativenumber?<CR>
```

If I assign the mapping to a function key above `<F4>`, e.g. `<F5>`, `<S-F7>` etc. I don't experience the behavior mentioned above. Also if I disable the `timeout` option with `set notimeout` it does seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I made the `<F4>` key apparently work in all modes by using `map <expr>` expression maps as follows:

```
MapOptToggle <F4> relativenumber
MapOptToggle! <S-F4> number

command! -bang -nargs=+ MapOptToggle call <SID>MapOptToggle(<bang>0, <f-args>)
function! s:MapOptToggle(bang, key, opt)
  function! s:ToggleOpt(opt)
    if mode() =~# '\vno?' || !&showmode
      exec 'set ' . a:opt . '! ' . a:opt . '?'
    else
      exec 'set ' . a:opt . '!'
    endif
    redraw
    return ''
  endfunction
  let a='noremap'
  let b='<unique> <silent> <expr> ' . a:key . ' <SID>ToggleOpt(' . string(a:opt) . ')'
  exec a . ' ' . b
  exec a . '! ' .  b
  exec 'set ' . (a:bang ? 'no' : '') . a:opt
endfunction
```

But still my answer doesn't explain the unpredictable behavior of the `imap` insert-mode map.

Answer (score 1):

That comment

```
especially occurs if I hold the <F4> key depressed.
```

hints that the problem is due to key-repeat (increasing repetition speed as you hold the key down) interfering with the timeout used to determine if an escape character is the beginning of a a function key, or the vi special character <kbd>escape</kbd>.  When vi (or vim) gets too many characters too fast, it sees the beginning of a function key as an escape, and (for instance) aborts the current insertion.

Some programs (such as xterm) will send vt100-style PF1-PF4 for <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F4</kbd>.  The resulting <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> is a vi command that puts you into insert-mode, allowing it to insert parts of the escape sequences that it reads.

Further reading:

- [VT220-Style Function Keys](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-VT220-Style-Function-Keys) (XTerm Control Sequences)